# Popular books on cutting-edge physics

Tags: black-holes, soft-question, resource-recommendations, quantum-information, quantum-entanglement

I watched this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3S0IGwKGV6s), in which different types of topics are discussed like Quantum Information, Quantum Computation, Universe as hologram, Hidden information, Quantum Entanglement, Black holes and Physics of information.

I have found this [book,](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/9812561315) which discusses these topics but it's very mathematically advanced. Can you recommend a popular book which talks about these topics but with little math?

Comment: If you are interested in the topics, why not try to learn the math?

Comment: "Mack the Knife" by Bertolt Brecht?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the question is "can you recommend a book that talks about these topics with minimal math," the answer is no. It would be even more confusing to describe quantum information and quantum computing without math than with the math, as the concepts aren't as intuitive as say general relativity, which can fairly effectively be described with mostly words. Math is also an integral part of our understanding of those things, much more so than with other concepts that can be understood with observational extrapolations.

Basically just learn the math.